# Are these 2 equations equal?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I was told to varify if the following two forms of the navier-stokes equation are equal (which the obviously should)

$$\rho \dfrac{d \vec{v}}{d t}  = \rho g-\nabla p+\eta \nabla^2 \vec{v}$$

$$\rho \left(\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{v}\right)= \rho g-\nabla p+\eta \nabla^2 \vec{v}$$

Therefor I had to verify that:
$$\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{v} =  \dfrac{d \vec{v}}{d t}$$
Using that $\vec{v} = (u,v,w)^T$
$$\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{v} =  \dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x} u +\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial y} v+\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial z} w$$
$$\Rightarrow(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{v} = \dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x} u +\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial y} v+\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial z} w$$

Using $\Rightarrow(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\\w \end{bmatrix}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}u \left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right)\\ v \left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right)\\w \left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}  \right)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} u+ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} v+ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} w\\ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} u+ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} v+ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial z} w\\
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} u+ \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y} v+ \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z} w \end{bmatrix}$$

And I do not see how these two should be equal as long as i am not allowed to change whatever is inside the derivative.

I am happy for any help!